# How to read DeltaLake table using Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, parquet, delta-lake, delta-live-tables

I have a deltalake table ( parquet format) in AWS S3 bucket. I need to read it in a dataframe using Pyspark in notebook code.
I tried searching online but no success yet. Can anyone share sample code of how to read a deltalake table in Pyspark ( dataframe or any other object).

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created the Delta Table, then you can read as Spark dataframe like below;

```py
s3_path = "s3://<bucket_name>/<delta_tables_path>/"
df = spark_session.read.load(s3_path)
df.show(n)
```

Comment: Thanks @Eren. In this case how do I authenticate to S3 bucket? where do I add the credentials?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant. You must already download the AWS CLI from this link; https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html and set your AWS profile like here; https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/keys-profiles-credentials.html. After all, you should be reading it smoothly.